# Eclipse WindowsBuilder: poder seleccionar solo 1 checkbox y no todos a la vez

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola,
Tengo ese programa listo pero, se pueden seleccionar todos los checkbox a la vez y no deseo eso. Hay alguna forma de que solo se puedan seleccionar 1 a la vez?.

Por ejemplo, en mi caso sería:

- Caso 1: Provincial, Franja 1, 2 y 3. Local desactivada.
- Caso 2: Local, todas las demás desactivadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definir un RadioButton:

```
JRadioButton rbtn1=new JRadioButton("txt1",true);
JRadioButton rbtn2=new JRadioButton("txt2",false);
JRadioButton rbtn3=new JRadioButton("txt3",false);
```

Creación del Grupo de Botones:

```
ButtonGroup grupo1 = new ButtonGroup();
grupo1.add(rbtn1);
grupo1.add(rbtn2);
grupo1.add(rbtn3);
```

La Clase que se utiliza se llama JRadioButton  Los parámetros que se pasan al momento de crearlo son el Texto que llevará y si estará seleccionado este ítem al momento de ejecutar nuestro programa.

ejemplos:

```
rbtn1.setText("Texto");
rbtn1.setSelected(true);
```

para realizar una accion :

```
if(rbtn1.isSelected()==true)
{
 System.out.print("Seleccionó opción 1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo con JRadioButton en lugar de un CheckBox, los RadioButton tienen la facilidad de diferenciarlos por grupo por lo que puedes hacer que solo seleccione 1 opcion por grupo! Saludos :)

Comment: Hola, perfecto. Sabes como diferenciarlos, cual seria el metodo?.